# "Thou shalt not throw" and noexcept

Tags: c++, exception, c++11, language-lawyer

The C++ standard sometimes uses the phrase "shall not throw exceptions", for instance in 17.6.3.4 when enumerating the `Hash` requirements. Does this imply that a standard-conforming implementation **must** mark the call operator of `std::hash` as `noexcept` or does this just implies that throwing from within a hash functor incurs in undefined or implementation-defined behaviour?

I checked that both libstdc++ and libc++ mark `std::hash`'s call operator as `noexcept`, but I would like to understand if this is a required behaviour or not.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"*Requires:* Thou shalt not throw" means exactly what you guessed:  If you throw, you will get undefined behavior.

Furthermore 17.6.5.12 [res.on.exception.handling]/p1 lets implementors add a *noexcept-specfication*:

> Any of the functions defined in the C++ standard library can report a
>   failure by throwing an exception of a type described in its Throws:
>   paragraph. An implementation may strengthen the exception
>   specification for a non-virtual function by adding a non-throwing
>   noexcept-specification.

libstdc++ and libc++ mark `std::hash`'s call operator as `noexcept` as a conforming extension.  They are allowed, but not required to do this.

Comment: Why is that allowed? It would tempt the programmer to write code that relies on the fact std::hash doesn't throw, which would not be portable. If you want some functions not to throw for performance - enforce that in spec, otherwise, never let anyone rely on it.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich: If I had to venture a guess, it is because of `unsorted_map`.  Having a blinding fast hash-map has rapidly become an essential feature of a modern language.  It is very difficult to implement this quickly without an exception guarantee on hash.  Consider how hard it would be to rehash a map if, half way through, a hash exception could force you to figure out how to unwind all of the completed rehashings.  Also consider that an unordered_map could not guarantee move mechanics without it.

Comment: It is a special case, and languages strive their best to avoid giving special treatment like that.  However, it has been seen in other languages that a powerful unordered hash map is a sufficiently powerful feature to warrant a special rule.  And `noexcept` is not quite the same... `noexecept` actually does force an exception handler which calls `terminate()` on any exception.  Often hashes are so cheap (ints often simply return their value), adding an exception handler would be overkill

Comment: @CortAmmon completely agree about `unsorted_map`. But I see no reason not to force implementation  to have `noexcept`.

Comment: @Elazar Leibovich: Another thing to consider is that the behavior of `noexcept` was added very late in the process.  The team found a major issue with how they were handling move mechanics and had to solve it before releasing the language.  They openly admitted that the handling of `noexecpt` was not quite up to the level they wanted it to be, but they needed to get a working language out the door.   (and you'll note that they did not force implementations to have `noexcept`, they merely made it undefined behavior to throw).

Comment: Public service announcement:  Anyone can file an issue against the standard, and it is easy to do so.  Here are step by step instructions for how to file a library issue: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue